# Stream Data Calculation In Flux

Tags: project-reactor

The following code illustrates a logic I need in a Spring Reactive project:

Inputs:

```
var period = 3;
int [] inArr = {2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 22 };
```

Calculation:

```
var upbond = inArr[0] + period;
var count =0;
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList();
for(int a: inArr){
  if(a <= upbond){
    count++;
  }else{
    result.add(count);
    count = 1;
    upbond += period;
  }
}
result.add(count);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
```

The data source of the sorted integers is the Flux from DB where it shall continually fetch data once a new suitable data is written into the DB. And the result shall be a stream that is sending out to another node through RSocket (by the request-stream communication mode).

After some online searching on Reactor, including some tutorials, I still can't figure out how to write the logic in the Flux fashion. The difficulty I have is that those calculations on data defined outside of the loop.

How shall I approach it in the Reactor?

Comment: Which one is the backing database?

Comment: For this case, I use H2 through the R2DBC drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`scan()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#scan-java.util.function.BiFunction-) variant that lets you use a separately typed accumulator is your friend here.

I'd approach this with a separate `State` class:

```
public class State {
    private int count;
    private Optional<Integer> upbond;
    private Optional<Integer> result;

    public State() {
        this.count = 0;
        this.upbond = Optional.empty();
        this.result = Optional.empty();
    }

    public State(int count, int upbond) {
        this.count = count;
        this.upbond = Optional.of(upbond);
        this.result = Optional.empty();
    }

    public State(int count, int upbond, int result) {
        this.count = count;
        this.upbond = Optional.of(upbond);
        this.result = Optional.of(result);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Optional<Integer> getUpbond() {
        return upbond;
    }

    public Optional<Integer> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

...and then use `scan()` to build up the state element by element:

```
sourceFlux
        .concatWithValues(0)
        .scan(new State(), (state, a) ->
                a <= state.getUpbond().orElse(a + period) ?
                        new State(state.getCount() + 1, state.getUpbond().orElse(a + period)) :
                        new State(1, state.getUpbond().orElse(a + period) + period, state.getCount())

        )
        .windowUntil(s -> s.getResult().isPresent())
        .flatMap(f -> f.reduce((s1, s2) -> s1.getResult().isPresent()?s1:s2).map(s -> s.getResult().orElse(s.getCount() - 1)))
```

Aside: The `concatWithValues()` / `windowUntil()` / `flatMap()` bits are there to handle the last element - there's probably a cleaner way of achieving that, if I think of it I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. I am trying to comprehend the approach.

Comment: @vic Thanks for the accept, but I'd honestly accept 123's answer, especially if you're newer to reactive - it's clearer and more easier to reason about what's going on. I'll just leave this here as an alternative - always more than one way to bake a cake.

Comment: Thanks for your input again. It is difficult for me to understand your approach at this moment. Once I get more knowledge on the Reactor, I will revisit your approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think scan is definitely the right tool here, combined with a stateful class, although my approach would be slightly different than Michaels.

Accumulator:

```java
class UpbondAccumulator{

    final Integer period;
    Integer upbond;
    Integer count;
    Boolean first;
    Queue<Integer> results;

    UpbondAccumulator(Integer period){
        this.period = period;
        this.count = 0;
        this.upbond = 0;
        this.results = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        this.first = true;
    }

    //Logic is inside accumulator, since accumulator is the only the only thing 
    //that needs it. Allows reuse of accumulator w/o code repetition
    public UpbondAccumulator process(Integer in){
        //If impossible value
        //Add current count to queue and return
        //You will have to determine what is impossible
        //Since we concat this value on the end of flux
        //It will signify the end of processing
        //And emit the last count 
        if(in<0){
            results.add(count);
            return this;
        }
        //If first value
        //Do stuff outside loop
        if(this.first) {
            upbond = in + period;
            first=false;
        }
        //Same as your loop
        if(in <= upbond)
            count++;
        else {
            results.add(count);
            count = 1;
            upbond += period;
        }
        //Return accumulator
        //This could be put elsewhere since it isn't
        //Immediately obvious that `process` should return
        //the object but is simpler for example
        return this;
    }

    public Mono<Integer> getResult() {
        //Return mono empty if queue is empty
        //Otherwise return queued result
         return Mono.justOrEmpty(results.poll());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
    dbFlux
            //Concat with impossible value
            .concatWithValues(-1)
            //Create accumulator, process value and return
            .scan(new UpbondAccumulator(period), UpbondAccumulator::process)
            //Get results, note if there are no results, this will be empty
            //meaning it isn't passed on in chain
            .flatMap(UpbondAccumulator::getResult)
```

---

Following comment from Michael here is an immutable approach

Accumulator:

```java
public class UpbondAccumulator{

    public static UpbondState process(int period,Integer in,UpbondState previous){

        Integer upbond = previous.getUpbond().orElse(in + period);
        int count = previous.getCount();

        if(in<0) return new UpbondState(upbond, count, count);

        if(in <= upbond) return new UpbondState(upbond,count + 1 , null);

        return new UpbondState(upbond + period, 1, count);
    }
}
```

State object:

```java
public class UpbondState {
    private final Integer upbond;
    private final int count;
    private final Integer result;

    public UpbondState() {
        this.count = 0;
        this.upbond = null;
        this.result = null;
    }

    public UpbondState(Integer upbond, int count,Integer result) {
        this.upbond = upbond;
        this.count = count;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public int getCount() { return count; }
    public Optional<Integer> getUpbond() { return Optional.ofNullable(upbond); }
    public Integer getResult() { return result; }
    public boolean hasResult() { return result!=null; }
}
```

Usage:

```java
    dbFlux
            .concatWithValues(-1)
            .scan(new UpbondState(), 
                    (prev, in) -> UpbondAccumulator.process(period,in,prev))
            //Could be switched for Optional, but would mean one more map
            //+ I personally think makes logic less clear in this scenario
            .filter(UpbondState::hasResult)
            .map(UpbondState::getResult)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. This approach is relatively easier to understand for me who is just starting using/learning Reactor.

Comment: I think I'd go for this answer tbh - it's clearer to reason about what's going on. The only thing I'm not so keen on is that `UpbondAccumulator` isn't immutable, but that's being a bit picky. (The impossible value is needed to force the "count" out of the flux at the end.)

Comment: @123 I have a close look at your approach. With your document along with your code, I can understand it. The impossible value is a marker of the end.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I thought that myself, but it didn't seem to cause any issues in testing. Added immutable approach anyway

Comment: @vic Yep, added clarification to comments

Comment: @123 It won't cause issues in this simple example - it just means there's the possibility for someone to create the same instance and then reuse it on multiple concurrent requests, which could then introduce a race hazard.

Comment: @MichaelBerry, yep that was my thinking